# detect if element changes in IE

Tags: javascript, events, binding, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to trigger something if an element changes to fix the fixed width and height of that element.

For that I found `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Now I'm trying to bind it: `$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#content", resizer);`

That works with Chrome or Firefox. But in IE11 it triggers the whole time. Is there another way to bind the `DOMSubtreeModified` event to an "later existing" element?

Comment: What kind of change are you trying to monitor?

Comment: anything that changes the width or height

Comment: Not sure why `DOMSubtreeModified` would be helpful since a change in size isn't necessarily a change to the DOM tree.

Comment: Also, [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) are deprecated.

Comment: I have fixed width and height. If something changes in the subtree, probably the width or the height changes too.

Comment: If the size is fixed, changes to the DOM Tree won't change the size of your element, only its position.

Comment: That's right, because that I need to check if the subtree changes to fix the width and height

Comment: Any chance using [Responsive Web Design](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) is the better way to go here?

Comment: Sadly no, I have shit code which I'm trying to repair.

Comment: Well, check out the library described in the link.

Comment: I'm just trying to find a simple way to trigger something when the subtree changes. I don't want to add a new library to the project

Comment: I am having the same issue now. Did you find any solution for this